# Почему не добавляется класс к элементу, выбранному по классу?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Почему то не добавляется класс к элементу с классом `block`, с помощью `element.classList.add('class')`, не добавляется другой класс?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>More Square</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button" id="click">
    </div>
    <div id="main">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
var block= document.getElementsByClassName('block');

click.onclick = function() {
   block.classList.add('block2');
}
```

Comment: так потому что `getELementsByClassName` возвращает коллекцию элементов.

Comment: То есть нельзя объекту с классом таким образом добавить другой класс?! Есть какой-то другой способ?

Comment: Либо перебирайте в цикле либо делайте вот так `getElementsByClassName('block')[0]`  для того чтобы получить первый блок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block'),
  click = document.querySelector('#click');

click.onclick = function() {
  for (let value of block) {
    value.classList.add('block2');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>More Square</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button" id="click">
    test
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло

Answer (score 0):

```js
var block = document.getElementsByClassName('block');

console.log( block );
/* Для демо. Возвращает объект, в котором по числовым ключам хранятся найденные элементы.

block[0] - будет первым таким классом, block[1] - вторым и т.п. */

document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < block.length; i++){
    block[i].classList.add('block2');
  }
});
```

```css
.block2 {background-color: orange;}
.block {width: 100px; height: 50px; border: 2px solid orange; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<button id="click">Click!</button>
<div id="main">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Цикл for берет и кругами выполняет то, что находится внутри. И на каждом круге переменная `i` является конкретным числом, которое можно использовать. Т.е. вместо

```
block[0].classList.add('block2');
block[1].classList.add('block2');
block[2].classList.add('block2');
```

Запускается один цикл.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял почему не будет работать

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Здравствуйте я так понял повесить событие на массив(коллекция) нельзя потому что кроме ключей у него length; itrm; namedItem ?

Comment: @leks Там всё куда сложнее (сам до конца не представляю), но наверно и этого хватит, чтобы понять принцип - https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/fs4xk0tj/ ) Первые 3 нормально срабатывают - а последний выдаёт ровно ту же ошибку, что и реальный ивент... потому что у полученных HTML-элементов есть встроенная функция, а у их общего объекта - нет такой.